# ZF2 JsonModel is Converting my String to NULL when using Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm creating a restFull API with ZF2 and I'm using Doctrine to help me with DB stuff.
As doctrine findAll() returns a array of Objects, I made a method called getData() inside every Entity in order to return its data as array...

In my Controller I get everything perfectly, but when I return JsonModel($myArrayList) some of the content are set NULL.

For example:
    **{"id":1,"name":null,"age":30}**

This is happening when the string has acents (Used in Portuguese / French / etc) "Luís" for example.

Any clues how to fix this problem ?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the encoding of such strings in getData() method using the following code:

```
    $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($str));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll have a try soon.